# Executing remote procedure with user-defined table type variable parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server, user-defined-types

I'm trying to call a remote stored procedure over a linked server. The problem is, one of the required parameters is a user-defined table types.

I can't seem to figure out how to declare a local variable as a user-defined table type from a remote server.

This is what I'm trying so far, but it doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @tblVar [REMOTESERVER].REMOTEDB.dbo.user_defined_table_type

EXEC [REMOTESERVER].REMOTEDB.dbo.procedure_name (@param1 = @tblVar)
```

However the error I'm getting is:

> The type name 'REMOTESERVER.REMOTEDB.dbo' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 1.
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@tblVar"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upon further research I discovered that table variables are invalid for remote procedure calls.

Instead, what I did was called `EXEC [REMOTESERVER].[REMOTEDB]..sp_executesql` and declared and populated my table variable and called the stored procedure all inside of that.

Example:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @SQL = N'
DECLARE @tblVar dbo.user_defined_table_type
-- Code to populate table here
EXEC dbo.procedure_name (@param1 = @tblVar)
'
EXEC [REMOTESERVER].[REMOTEDB]..sp_executesql @stmt = @SQL
```

And that solved my problem. Hopefully this will help someone else out in the future.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question!