# Unexplained declaration error on dynamic sql with output executed on linked server

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, linked-server

I'm trying to get an output value from a dynamic sp_executesql query on a remote linked server for MS SQL Server, although the query works, I keep getting the following error

```
running query for foo
```

> Must declare the scalar variable "@countOUT"

```
4
```

My query is

```
declare @count int
set @sqlcmd = 'select @countOUT = count(*) from '+@instance+'.'+@databasename+'.dbo.SomeTable where size=1';
print 'running query for '+@databasename;
exec sp_executesql @sqlcmd, N'@countOUT int OUTPUT',@countOUT=@count OUTPUT
print @count
```

It prints out the correct value for @count retrieved from the query.
I've followed the MSDN guide and looked at any stackoverflow questions, but all seem to point that my query should work. Without errors.

Comment: This may be solved by running `sp_executesql` on the remote linked server instead of locally: `exec [server].[database]..sp_executesql`.  See this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719738/executing-remote-procedure-with-user-defined-table-type-variable-parameter

Comment: Cannot reproduce on SQL Server 2014. Post the full code that reproduces this error. This isn't it. For instance,  `@sqlcmd`, `@instance` and `@databasename` are not declared. Reduce the query to bare essentials (`select @countOUT = 1`) and see where stuff is really failing.

Comment: @MartinParkin Thanks I'll try that. If you put it in an answer I can select it as best answer if it works? I suspect it will, will try it soon.

Comment: It seems it did work, thanks @MartinParkin. I didn't notice the change in calling the exec on the target server itself :/